# How can I get C++11 library support with the Intel compiler on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, c++11, icc

I want to port a fairly large and still-growing C++ application from PC to Mac, and continue to support development in parallel on both platforms.  On the PC we're using MSVC2010, and deploying a few C++11 features.  On the Mac we're using XCode 4.0.2.  To improve platform agnosticism and support the inline assembly we're using, we're deploying the Intel compiler on both.  However, the compiler doesn't come with a library, so we're reliant on those supplied by the vendors.  On the Mac, that means no C++11 library support, for features we're very keen to use such as std::forward and so on.  I can't build libc++ with the Intel compiler on the Mac otherwise my problems would be solved.  Is there a way around this other than rolling our own libraries?

Comment: Install a virtual machine and run a simple Linux distro such as Ubuntu server (allowing you to skip X11, GUIs, ...).  These tend to have current g++ versions which are close to final drafts of what is now C++11.

Comment: What do you mean "on the Mac, that means to C++11 library support"?  I won't vouch for `std::forward` in particular, but clang (llvm's C++ compiler) supports many C++11 features, and it ships with Xcode 4.x.

Comment: Dirk: To be clear, this is a commercial application. It needs to run on OSX. If you can achieve that without building on OSX I'm all ears.
Richard: libc++ can indeed be built with Clang and offer extensive C++11 support.  However, libc++ cannot be built with the Intel compiler (unless someone can show me how?).  I would cheerfully pile through the library to fix the Intel compiler errors, but my employers may be a little grumpy about that if it would take longer than essentially rolling our own support for move constructors and assignment operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot switch to a different compiler on Mac, I would suggest contacting Intel's User Support, to let them know that C++11 support is important to you, and to ask them how actively they are implementing it, now that the new language is an ISO standard.

It's just possible that they may also be aware of a working library.

Answer (score 1):

Clang and Intel 15 both support C++11 on Mac and Linux.  Official websites describe the status of C++11 features of the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) and [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) compilers.

On Mac, the Intel compiler uses the system C++ library, which presumably is associated with the included Clang/LLVM toolchain.

```
$ otool -L threads
threads:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

The `threads` program can be any program that calls a `std::thread` call, e.g.

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread::id id;
}
```

Comment: Citation needed. In particular you need to say what standard library will be used by ICC.

Comment: I do not know how to cite my own original research on this topic, e.g. verifying that codes like https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/c%2B%2B11/threads.cxx run fine with Intel 15.

Comment: Please remove your downvote now, as I have cited the exact thing you requested.

Comment: Yes, libc++ is the Clang standard library. Thanks! (By the way, this site prefers describing a reproducible process to citation. So you could say `icc - < (echo '#include <iostream>'; echo 'int main() { std::cout << "hi\n"; }'); otool -L a.out` if that works. Or, without providing instructions, just mention that you compiled a program and used `otool`. There are a lot of lazy answers on SO, so just be sure not to appear as such.)